# Initializing Parallax position values after page refresh

Tags: javascript, scroll, parallax, fade, page-refresh

This may well have been asked before but I have an issue with a parallax effect I have deployed on an image slider. On scroll, the background images being used in the slider adjust their position and their opacity.

The problem is if I scroll a short way down the page and then refresh the page, the background position and the opacity revert to their original values, so then scrolling causes a jump in order for them 'catch up' on what their actual values should be.

I'm trying to figure out how I can have the values automatically set no matter what position the page is in when it's refreshed.

Here is the code that I have currently

```
//HomepageParallaxFade
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  var bgParallax = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-cell');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(bgParallax, function (el) {
    var limit = el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight;
    if (scrollPosition > el.offsetTop && scrollPosition <= limit) {
      el.style.backgroundPositionY = (50 + 90 * scrollPosition / limit) + '%';
      el.style.opacity = (1 - 1 * scrollPosition / limit);
    } else {
      el.style.backgroundPositionY = '50%';
    }
  })
});
```

Happy to provide a JSFiddle if necessary. All help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do parallax with pure css.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-pure-css-parallax.

From there, when you refresh if you set the scroll position with javascript, the parallax will just work.